# Using Java generics while inheriting from an abstract class

Tags: java, generics

I want to extends a generic typ from an abstract class:

```
abstract class Foo {
    public void doStuff() {}
}

public class Bar<T extends Foo> {
    public void doFooBar(Foo param) {
        /* Code here */
        param.doStuff();
    }
}
```

In other words: A class Bar should created with an generic type, which extends from Foo. Bar should be able to have methods, where Foo is an parameter (because the generic type extends from Foo, so it should be possible).
Using instead of Foo a predefined class like String oder BigDecimal, it works so far. But in my case, Bar complains about not finding class Foo.
I'm using Eclipse.

Did I miss something?

**SOLUTION:**
Foo has to be a public modifier, than it works. I expected, that abstract class are public by default (like Interfaces). Eclipse doesn't complain about the missing modifier.

Comment: In the code you posted `Bar` DOES NOT extend `Foo`.  It is an independent class (extends `Object`) that is parameterized with `Foo` or a subtype of `Foo`.  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I correct my description.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Foo() {
    ...
```

is a syntax error.

Correcting that to

```
abstract class Foo { 
    ...
```

results in no compilation errors.  Also, note that it should probably be

```
public class Bar<T extends Foo> {
    public void doFooBar(T param) {
// ----------------------^
// Type parameter here

        /* Code here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Foo without brackets... that's clear (fu## typo). Using T to call method doesn't work.

Comment: Eclipse isn't able to resolve Foo to a type. Even import the model per hand doesn't work.

Comment: My Eclipse compiles it just fine.  You're doing something your're not showing in your post.

Comment: I was able to fix it. Please see my  original post.

Comment: Were the two classes in different files?

Comment: Next time, please provide ALL the pertinent information. The fact that they are in different files (actually in different packages) is CRITICAL to understanding this problem. You waste other peoples' time when you omit important details.

Comment: Yes, Sir. I will do.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the () parantheses after classname Foo

#### Here is modified code:

```
abstract class Foo {
    public void doStuff() {}
}
```

Comment: Your "modified" code looks same as author's question. What is modified? For now it is not an answer.